# Watercolor is by reputation an amateur's medium

Tags: prepositions, complements, adverbial-phrases

consider:

> Watercolor is by reputation an amateur's medium.

I think I can rephrase above sentence as below:

> From the reputation point of view, watercolor is an amateur's medium.

Am I right?

If the answer is yes, can we always use "Noun + be + By + Noun" to explain an especial aspect of the subject rather using conjunctive adverbs, "*From the bla bla point of view*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your rewrite is not correct. The original message is saying that it is an established fact that watercolor is used by amateurs in painting. Your rewrite is considering reputation as a distinct attribute of watercolor and asserting that only when considering this attribute, it's for amateurs.

Correct rewrites might include:

> Watercolor is known for its use by amateurs.
>
> It's a well known fact that amateurs use watercolor.
>
> Amateurs prefer watercolor.
>
> Watercolor is exclusively reserved for use in first grade classrooms.

As someone who paints in other mediums (I dare not refer to myself as an artist), it just goes without saying that anyone remotely serious about the craft doesn't use watercolor. It takes a great deal more skill and work to properly paint in a medium with texture and weight, such as acrylic and then of course oil.

In case you missed it, this is a statement of elitism, which are almost always false and only a reflection of personal preference. Different artists work in different mediums, and just like anywhere in human society where people do things differently, some are going to claim to be better than others.

My answer doesn't quite answer every aspect of your question, I'll leave that open to additional answers.

Comment: Technik -- You might be selling yourself short.  I have seen many wonderful watercolor paintings.

Comment: @Jasper lol I thought about changing my remarks. I know it's not universally true, it's more an elitism thing among painters from other mediums.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, may you explain the "is by reputation" structure? I mean grammar and these sort of things.